# How do I go about link web content in a database with a nested set model?

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2000, nested-sets

My nested set table is as follows.

```
 create table depts (
  id int identity(0, 1) primary key
  , lft int
  , rgt int
  , name nvarchar(60)
        , abbrv nvarchar(20)
 );
```

Test departments.

```
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (1, 14, 'root', 'r');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (2, 3, 'department 1', 'd1');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (4, 5, 'department 2', 'd2');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (6, 13, 'department 3', 'd3');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (7, 8, 'sub department 3.1', 'd3.1');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (9, 12, 'sub department 3.2', 'd3.2');
insert into depts (lft, rgt, name, abbrv) values (10, 11, 'sub sub department 3.2.1', 'd3.2.1');
```

My web content table is as follows.

```
 create table content (
  id int identity(0, 1)
  , dept_id int
  , page_name nvarchar(60)
  , content ntext
 );
```

Test content.

```
insert into content (dept_id, page_name, content) 
 values (3, 'index', '<h2>welcome to department 3!</h2>');
insert into content (dept_id, page_name, content) 
 values (4, 'index', '<h2>welcome to department 3.1!</h2>');
insert into content (dept_id, page_name, content) 
 values (6, 'index', '<h2>welcome to department 3.2.1!</h2>');
insert into content (dept_id, page_name, content) 
 values (2, 'what-doing', '<h2>what is department 2 doing?/h2>');
```

I'm trying to query the correct page content (from the content table) based on the url given. I can easily accomplish this task with a root department. However, querying a department with multiple depths is proving to be a little harder. For example:

```
http://localhost/departments.asp?d3/ (Should return <h2>welcome to department 3!</h2>)
http://localhost/departments.asp?d2/what-doing (Should return <h2>what is department 2 doing?</h2>)
```

I'm not sure if this can be create in one query or if there will need to be a recursive function of some sort. Also, if there is nothing after the last / then assume we want the index page.

This would basically be the back end of a small CMS. So my thought was that you could create new pages with a unique name associated to a category. Which in my case, would be departments. I have looked around and there aren't very many choices in terms of CMS for ASP Classic.

How can this be accomplished? Comments and suggestions also welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something *very* similar to this (except with PHP/MySQL).  I don't have the code in front of me, but I would be happy to supply it to you if you think it might help:

I believe the main difference in my approach was that I didn't have a separate table with the nested set, I just had content and lft/rgt together in one table.  The content management allowed the user to create a content hierarchy with as much depth as they dared, so the site could turn out something like:

```
http://site/tier1-page
http://site/tier1-page/tier2-pageA
http://site/tier1-page/tier2-pageB
http://site/tier1-page/tier2-pageB/tier3-pageI
http://site/tier1-page/tier2-pageB/tier3-pageII
```

...and so on.

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you posted your solution.

Comment: hit me up on twitter or something and I'll send you a copy